# Let flash messages disappear by clicking it, in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have standard flash messages throughout my app, using bootstrap for styling. These work fine but I would like to add a functionality.
 A visitor who gets a flash message on his/her screen, should have the ability to click the flash message away / to make flash message disappear. For example a X in the top right corner that if clicked, removes the flash message. *Is this possible (without javascript)?* I have added my current code, which does not allow for such behavior, below. How should I adjust my code for this behavior?

---

Currently, I for example have in my controller:

```
flash.now[:info] = "Your subscription has expired"
```

In application.html.erb:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
<% end %>
```

And I have a partial _error_messages.html.erb:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using `Devise`?

Comment: No, not using Devise.

Comment: Hmm ok. Add this `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>` after the `content_tag` and check.

Comment: Thanks, I added that as a 3rd line to `application.html.erb`. Now a small x shows up below (would prefer to have it inside) the flash message. Clicking the x doesn't do anything, though. Also looking at it with the inspector in Firefox, it doesn't light up which it would if it would be changing any style.

Comment: Oops. Try putting it inside the `content_tag` like `<%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") do %><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><% end %>`

Comment: Yes, now the x shows up inside the flash bar and clicking it removes the flash bar from the screen. However, now the message itself, inside the flash bar, does not exist from the start (checked the source code and the text indeed is gone completely).

Comment: I've posted my answer.Try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81081/discussion-between-pavan-and-nick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving it like this

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Update**

This should work

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}" do -%>
  <%= message %>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wont work since the button needs to be in the flash div.

Comment: Thanks, it did work. Only disadvantage is the styling. The first div always shows up, also if there's no flash message. The first `div` assumes an info flash message, but that doesn't apply to all flash messages. And 2nd `div` of the flash message has a border inside the 1st `div`. But all of this styling can of course be adapted.

Comment: Not to be a nag, but why not just do it right? See my answer.

Comment: @Nick What's the problem with my second suggestion in comments. i.e, `<%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") do %><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><% end %>`?

Comment: Then the text "Your subscription has expired" is no longer present. So it's just an empty message bar. I checked the source code and the text doesn't exist anywhere in the source code (while it does with the original code).

Comment: @Nick Check my updated answer. I had given `do` in wrong place in my previous comment

Comment: This generated an error message on loading the page: `unexpected keyword_do, expecting ')' ...alert alert-#{message_type}" do) );@output_buffer.safe_appen... ... `

Comment: The page now indeed loads, but still with an empty message bar.

Comment: @Nick Now check please.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution available without using javascript is to reload the page but it is not a viable solution.

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, 
      message + link_to('x', request.path), 
      class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") 
  %>
<% end %>
```

Since flashes are removed from the session after they are displayed there would be no flash messages.

However you can use the javascript functionality built into bootstrap without actually writing any javascript (I stole this from Pavan's comment).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flashes">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    You forgot the lights on! <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    You forgot the stove on! <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Added:

To integrate this into your Rails app:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="<%= "alert alert-#{message_type}" %>">
    <%= message %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

While you could use `content_tag` and cram the spans in this is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the `flash.each` code to `application.html.erb`. I'm not really sure where to add the `button` code in my code. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Added an implementation suggestion

Comment: For some reason the 'x' on the screen is not clickable, just plain text.

Comment: Are you sure you have the bootstrap javascript installed correctly and there are no script errors on the page? You can see on the snippet above that it does work.

Comment: I belief it is correctly installed, the bootstrap styling is working throughout the app. I also added the three lines (script, script, link) to check if that made a difference, but it didn't.

Comment: Did you check the console in your browser?

Comment: That's new for me. I checked and there are quite a few (CSS) errors. But I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I checked if perhaps "sr-only" existed amongst the errors but it didn't.

Comment: `sr-only` means that the element is only shown to screen readers. Check if the html output matches what you expect or even copy paste the mocked flash messages from my snippet into your app. I'm pretty convinced that there is something screwy with your app.

Comment: In terms of looks it absolutely fits what I would expect. For example, also the styling for the flash message is correct: different colors depending on the kind of message (info, danger, success). So, since this styling comes from bootstrap, it must be installed... Also, the solution given by Pavan, right above "Update" does work functionally (suggesting bootstrap is working) but has styling issues.

Comment: I totally forgot to add the `<button>` tag. Really sorry for wasting your time. edited the answer.

Comment: No problem Maxcal, I also learned about the console. I tried it and can confirm the code now works.